# How to return results from a JobService?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm playing a bit with Android and writing a small app with an activity and a service. The activity starts the service on button click and it should fetch some data from a URI and return it as a result. Sometimes, data is not available or doesn't meet a criteria, and then the service should retry every X minutes even if the activity is in the background.

I've implemented the communication between the activity and the service via `Intent` and `ResultReceiver` (passed in the bundle). When implementing the service, I wanted to use the new `JobScheduler` component but then saw it can only accept a `PersistableBundle` which can't add a `Parcelable` object (`ResultReceiver`) but only the basic types.

I want the service to schedule a job that will run when network is available and every X minutes to check for data. Once it gets it, I want the data to be returned to **the service** so it can decide if it's acceptable or we need to retry again. If the service accepts the data, it will return it to the activity via the `ResultsReceiver`.

I can't use `ResultsReceiver` with the `JobService`, and it since I don't construct the `JobService` instance (done by the `JobInfo.Builder`), I can't pass it a reference to a callback object.

How can I communicate between a scheduled job and the service that invoked it?

Sorry if it's trivial, I'm not familiar with Android..

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I communicate between a scheduled job and the service that invoked it?

Generally, you don't. Neither your service nor your activity are likely to exist. The point behind `JobScheduler` is to have jobs run when your app is no longer running. If you are using it in other ways, that may not be appropriate.

That being said, you are welcome to use an event bus (greenrobot's EventBus would be my choice, though `LocalBroadcastManager` would work here as well), to raise an event within your process to say that the job is completed. Your service (or activity) could register for events on the bus and react when those events are raised. Yet, at the same time, event buses are perfectly content to let events "fall on the floor" if there are no registered handlers, so your `JobService` can just raise the event in a "fire and forget" mode if desired.

Comment: can i send data from JobScheduler to Activity using LocalBroadcastManager and update the UI based on updated value fetched from LocalBroadCast Receivers?

Comment: @JayDangar: In principle, yes. Bear in mind that your activity may not exist, though.

Comment: @CommonWare, Using broadcast receivers i can solve that problem? can i? I mean combination of localBroadcast manager and Broadcastreceivers. I am not sure.

Comment: @JayDangar: Sorry, but I am uncertain what "that problem" is. `JobScheduler` is designed for jobs that might happen minutes, hours, or days in the future. There is no guarantee that you have a *process* around, let alone a UI. Android will fork a process for you, but that is it. So, using `LocalBroadcastManager` is fine for updating a UI if it happens to exist. If `sendBroadcast()` returns `false`, you know that no UI responded to the local broadcast, and your `JobService` can do something else (e.g., raise a `Notification`).

Comment: Yes, my "that problem" was regarding UI update using LocalBroadCast manager, which i have solved using sharedpreferences. which will update the data in shared preferences using jobscheduler and using onsharedpreferences data change something like that callback i am able to update my data as well in UI side. so no need to use broadcast receivers.thogh it can also solve your problem.